# Will duplicated documents impact search results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Will duplicated documents impact search results?

For example, we have an index that we can have the same documents repeated and different by only one field.

Index: ChannelID, ProductID, ProductName and ProductDescription

We may have the same product on different ChannelIDs. So, if we have 100 ChannelIDs, we will have 100 times the same product (document) if this product is available is on all channels.

When doing a search, because of these repetition of documents (same product name, description), will it impact the results quality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your search, similar documents would all show up in search results. For example, in your ‘100 different channel ids but same product’ example, if one searches by product description (assuming the same product gets the same description), all of the 100 documents of that product would either be returned if the search matched or none of them will.

Comment: Ok. I think you are right if I search cross channels. What if I filter it through channelid? 

I have a feeling it will work as well. My concern is about the search results quality. For example. Because I have 100 times product A repeated because it is also available on the others 100 channels, when I do a search within that channel, even if I am filtering, because the Product A has duplicates on the DB, it may get boosted on the results compared to other products that are available on fewer channels. 

Will this, then, impact the results quality?

Thanks.

Comment: Identical fields in multiple documents will not generally boost up their relevance, and in fact on certain cases may do the opposite (a key word is less important if it's common), it depends on the actual queries you plan to use